# Rails: `next` method stops working after moving it to rails partial - Invalid next error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, partial-views

My current `ERB` file is as follows (which works fine),

```
<div>
  <% [1,2,3,4,5].each do |el| %>
    <% next if (el == 1) %>
    <span><%= el %></span>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

After I try to refactor the code and using rails partials, it looks as follow,

```
<div>
  <% [1,2,3,4,5].each do |el| %>
    <%= render partial: "element", locals: {el: el} %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And my partial `_element.html.erb` is,

```
<% next if (el == 1) %>
<span><%= el %></span>
```

This refactor causes an issue `SyntaxError (_element.html.erb:40: Invalid next)`

I'm not sure why `next` stops working after moving it to partial. Any workaround would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I bet you shouldn't use  `next` into partial, as it is a part of `.each` loop.

Comment: first there is a spelling mistake `loclas` should be `locals`. Second you could do this `<%= render(partial: 'element',locals:{el:el}) unless el ==1 %>` . The problem you are having is that the partial has no context to the the block itself the render method is simply being called for each `el` in turn. Imagine if you wanted to use this partial elsewhere and it was not in a loop. How would you expect that to function?

Comment: @engineersmnky - Thanks for spotting typo, corrected it. And my requirement is not as simple as I mentioned above. I cannot show all my code here so I tried to post similar problem with simple lines of code. But please consider that I am using this partial in both the places where loop is defined and the partial is fully written with conditions, so your suggested solution does not work for me though your intention is correct. Is there anything I can just do in place of `next` in my above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Answer to your current problem*:

Next cannot be used outside the context of a block and for good reason. How would you expect this to function

```
 def some_method(s)
   next unless s
   s
 end
```

Obviously inside a block it might make sense

```
[nil,2,3,nil,4].map {|n| some_method(n) } # sure kind of makes sense
#but what happens when I call
some_method(nil)
#how would you like it to use the next call here
#next what; there is no next; you have reached the end of the universe
```

*Feasible Workaround*:

Since you are fairly set on this concept and the code in my comment seems to be unacceptable to you.  You could try this instead:

```
<div>
    <% [1,2,3,4,5].each do |el| %>
        <%= render partial: "element", locals: {el: el} %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

partial `_element.html.erb`

```
 <%= content_tag(:span,el) unless el == 1 %>
```

You can substitute `el == 1` for what ever your actual condition is but if the condition is true it will not render the span tag otherwise it will render

```
 <span>Whatever el is here</span>
```

[`#content_tag` Docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag) because I find it a lot nicer than using `html_safe` or `raw` unless you really need to.

Comment: engineersmnky - Thanks! This sounds reasonable. I got it working with `unless` instead `next`. I understand `next` cannot be used outside the context of a block and for good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that partials are compiled into methods in a dynamically generated view class, you can get the desired effect by substituting `return` instead of `next`. It will short-circuit the rendering of your partial template and the loop will continue with the next element of the enumeration.

Hence your partial `_element.html.erb` would read:

`<% return if (el == 1) %>
<span><%= el %></span>`